# Unable to get my range slider to display value correctly

Tags: javascript, html

Problem: I can't get my range slider to display current value while end user adjust the slider location.  However, when the end user selects generate password, it does update the current value.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to function the way I would like it to?

Thank you.

```js
// var rangeInput = document.getElementById("slider1").value;



document.getElementById('num').addEventListener("change", function() {
  let value = document.getElementById("slider1").value;
  document.getElementById("num").textContent = value;
  console.log(value);
}, false);


//generate a password

function passwordGenerator () {

    // how long is the password going to be?
    var passwordLength = document.getElementById('num').value;

   
  // characters options for PW

  const values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLabcdefghikk0123456789!@#$%";

  
  // defining password
  var password = "";


// creating a loop to choose password

for (var i = 1; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
    password = password + values.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(values.length -1)));
}
  
// adding the password to the content area


document.getElementById('num').textContent = (passwordLength);
document.getElementById('display').value = password;

}


//copy to clipboard
function selectText() {
  const input = document.getElementById('display');
  input.focus();
  input.select();
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
```

```css
.backgroundWhite {

    background-color: white;
    border: darkgray 2px solid;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}


.backgroundGray {
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500%;
}

.passwordBox {

    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}


body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.headText {
    padding: 50px;
}

.buttonOnClick {
    margin: 20px;
}
.passGenButton {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 15%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.copyButton {
    margin-left: 15%;
    background-color: darkgray;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

textarea {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 27px;
color: #4f4f4f;
}

.titleClass {

    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Random Password Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="conatiner backgroundGray">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="topText">
                    <h1 class="text-center text-dark headText">Password Generator</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="container">
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <div class="content backgroundWhite">
                                <h4 class="titleClass">Generate a Password</h4>
                                <br />
                                
                                
                           
                                <!-- Slider -->
                                <div class="slidecontainer">
                                    <input id="slider1" type="range" min="8" max="128" value="8" onchange="num.value=value" class="robClass"> 
                                    <span id="num">8</span>
                                </div>

                            <!--     <input id="slider1" type='range' min='8' max='128' value="8" onchange="rangevalue.value=value"
                                    class="robClass">
                                <span id='sliderValue'></span>-->
                                <br />


                                <textarea class="passwordBox" type="text" id="display" placeholder="Your Secure Password"></textarea>
                                <br />
                                <button onclick="passwordGenerator()" class="passGenButton buttonOnClick">Generate Password</button>
                                <button class="buttonOnClick copyButton" onclick="selectText()">Copy to clipboard</button>
                                <div id='length'></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because you `addEventlistener` to wrong element; `#num` is not the one you change but `slider1`

Correct your id to
`document.getElementById('slider1').addEventListener("change", function() {}, false);`

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of things that you needed to modify. I have added comments in the code below to the modifications that were made.

```js
// var rangeInput = document.getElementById("slider1").value;


/*
document.getElementById('num').addEventListener("change", function() {
  let value = document.getElementById("slider1").value;
  document.getElementById("num").textContent = value;
  console.log(value);
}, false);
*/

const slider = document.getElementById("slider1");
const sliderValue = document.getElementById("num");

// set the current value
sliderValue.innerHTML = slider.value;

// add an 'oninput' handler, set the "num" display to the current value
slider.oninput = function() {
  sliderValue.innerHTML = this.value;
}

//generate a password
function passwordGenerator() {
  // characters options for PW
  const values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLabcdefghikk0123456789!@#$%";
  // how long is the password going to be?
  //var passwordLength = document.getElementById('num').value;
  let passwordLength = document.getElementById('num').innerHTML; // use innerHTML not value here
  // defining password
  let password = "";
  // creating a loop to choose password
  for (var i = 1; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
    // instead of `password = password + values.charAt(....)` just use password += ....
    password += values.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(values.length - 1)));
  }
  // adding the password to the content area
  // document.getElementById('num').textContent = (passwordLength);
  // document.getElementById('display').value = password;    
  let slider = document.getElementById("slider1"); // set the slider back to default of 8 and invoke the oninput event
  slider.value = 8; // use value here not textContent
  slider.oninput.apply(slider); // programmatically call the `oninput` event
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = password; // use innerHTML here not value
}

//copy to clipboard
function selectText() {
  const input = document.getElementById('display');
  input.focus();
  input.select();
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
```

```css
.backgroundWhite {
  background-color: white;
  border: darkgray 2px solid;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.backgroundGray {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500%;
}

.passwordBox {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.headText {
  padding: 50px;
}

.buttonOnClick {
  margin: 20px;
}

.passGenButton {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 15%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.copyButton {
  margin-left: 15%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

textarea {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #4f4f4f;
}

.titleClass {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <title>Random Password Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="conatiner backgroundGray">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="topText">
          <h1 class="text-center text-dark headText">Password Generator</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
          <div class='row'>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
              <div class="content backgroundWhite">
                <h4 class="titleClass">Generate a Password</h4>
                <br />
                <!-- Slider -->
                <div class="slidecontainer">
                  <input id="slider1" type="range" min="8" max="128" value="8" class="robClass">
                  <span id="num">8</span>
                </div>
                <br />
                <textarea class="passwordBox" type="text" id="display" placeholder="Your Secure Password"></textarea>
                <br />
                <button onclick="passwordGenerator()" class="passGenButton buttonOnClick">Generate Password</button>
                <button class="buttonOnClick copyButton" onclick="selectText()">Copy to clipboard</button>
                <div id='length'></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Without changing most of your original code, I just added a new function which saves the value for `num` as `slider1`'s value and then updated the `textContent` of `num`.

`function sliderMove(){
document.getElementById('num').value = document.getElementById('slider1').value;
document.getElementById('num').textContent = document.getElementById('num').value;
}`

and then just call the `sliderMove()` function in the `onchange` of the `input` tag

`<input id="slider1" type="range" min="8" max="128" value="8" onchange="sliderMove()" class="robClass">`

Probably not the best solution but it seems to work for me. Hopefully this helps.

```js
// var rangeInput = document.getElementById("slider1").value;



document.getElementById('num').addEventListener("change", function() {
  let value = document.getElementById("slider1").value;
  document.getElementById("num").textContent = value;
  console.log(value);
}, false);


//generate a password

function passwordGenerator () {

    // how long is the password going to be?
    var passwordLength = document.getElementById('num').value;

   
  // characters options for PW

  const values = "ABCDEFGHIJKLabcdefghikk0123456789!@#$%";

  
  // defining password
  var password = "";


// creating a loop to choose password

for (var i = 1; i <= passwordLength; i++) {
    password = password + values.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(values.length -1)));
}
  
// adding the password to the content area


document.getElementById('num').textContent = (passwordLength);
document.getElementById('display').value = password;

}

function sliderMove(){
document.getElementById('num').value = document.getElementById('slider1').value;
document.getElementById('num').textContent = document.getElementById('num').value;
}

//copy to clipboard
function selectText() {
  const input = document.getElementById('display');
  input.focus();
  input.select();
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
```

```css
.backgroundWhite {

    background-color: white;
    border: darkgray 2px solid;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}


.backgroundGray {
    background-color: lightgray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500%;
}

.passwordBox {

    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}


body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.headText {
    padding: 50px;
}

.buttonOnClick {
    margin: 20px;
}
.passGenButton {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 15%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.copyButton {
    margin-left: 15%;
    background-color: darkgray;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

textarea {
padding: 20px;
font-size: 27px;
color: #4f4f4f;
}

.titleClass {

    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Random Password Generator</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="conatiner backgroundGray">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="topText">
                    <h1 class="text-center text-dark headText">Password Generator</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="container">
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 text-center">
                            <div class="content backgroundWhite">
                                <h4 class="titleClass">Generate a Password</h4>
                                <br />
                                
                                
                           
                                <!-- Slider -->
                                <div class="slidecontainer">
                                    <input id="slider1" type="range" min="8" max="128" value="8" onchange="sliderMove()" class="robClass"> 
                                    <span id="num">8</span>
                                </div>

                            <!--     <input id="slider1" type='range' min='8' max='128' value="8" onchange="rangevalue.value=value"
                                    class="robClass">
                                <span id='sliderValue'></span>-->
                                <br />


                                <textarea class="passwordBox" type="text" id="display" placeholder="Your Secure Password"></textarea>
                                <br />
                                <button onclick="passwordGenerator()" class="passGenButton buttonOnClick">Generate Password</button>
                                <button class="buttonOnClick copyButton" onclick="selectText()">Copy to clipboard</button>
                                <div id='length'></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```